Not getting events/returnValues in my transaction/recipt object
I was currently making a Dapp where in between I had to take the emitted values from events in my React application.
Here is the function's main logic
try{
        const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);
        const signer = await provider.getSigner();
        await provider.send('eth_requestAccounts', []);
        const currentAccount = await signer.getAddress();

        console.log("Current Account:", currentAccount);
        console.log("Contributing to Project ID:", projectId);
        console.log("Contributing Amount (ETH):", ethAmount.toString());
        console.log("Contributor ID:", contributorId);

        const contract = new ethers.Contract(Contract_Address, abi.abi, signer);

        const tx = await contract.contribute(projectId, contributorId, { value: ethAmount });
        const receipt = await tx.wait(); 
        console.log("Contribution transaction confirmed");

        const event = receipt.events.find(event => event.event === "ContributionReceived");
        if (event) {
            const { contributor, amount, equivalentUSD } = event.args;
            console.log("Contribution Event:", contributor, amount.toString(), equivalentUSD.toString());

            const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/projects/${projectId}/contribute`, {
                amount: ethers.utils.formatUnits(equivalentUSD, 18), // Format the equivalent USD
                contributorId,
            });

            if (response.status === 200) {
                alert("Payment successful!");
                onSuccess();
            } else {
                alert("Payment failed. Please try again.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Contribution event not found. Please check the transaction.");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Payment error:", error);
        alert("There was an error processing your payment. Please try again.");
    }

Here is my Smart Contract for contribute function
function contribute(string memory _projectId, string memory _contributorId) public payable {
        Project storage project = projects[_projectId];

        require(msg.value > 0, "Contribution must be greater than 0");
        require(!project.isCompleted, "Project funding is already completed");

        project.fundsRaised += msg.value;

 
        if (project.contributions[_contributorId] == 0) {
            project.contributors.push(Contributor(_contributorId, msg.value));
        } else {
            for (uint i = 0; i < project.contributors.length; i++) {
                if (keccak256(bytes(project.contributors[i].contributorAddress)) == keccak256(bytes(_contributorId))) {
                    project.contributors[i].amount += msg.value;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        project.contributions[_contributorId] += msg.value;

        uint contributionInUSD = (msg.value * getLatestETHUSDPrice()) / 1e18;

        emit ContributionReceived(_projectId, _contributorId, msg.value, contributionInUSD);
    }

This is my receipt object
Recipt Object + the Error
I tried many things but failed
I tried deploying ( npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia ) many times still the same result neither of the returns is working nor event
Please tell something to resolve this issue, how I can log the event value.
